# Twilio is it possible to play a recorded message

Tags: ruby, twilio

Is it possible with twilio to call somebody and then simply play an recorded mp3 for example?
It would be nice if you reference to the twilio api! I couldn't find there anything!

Comment: Did you consider asking Twilio???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in the Twilio API: [Twilio twiML API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play)

Follow their format for playing an audio file during the voice call